# Selection Sort confusion

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am doing a simple selection sort in ruby but I am sorting in descending order. It's confusing me because this work for all of my data except for one number.

```
def parallel_sort(data, labels)
    raise "unequal array lengths" if  data.length != labels.length
    temp = File.open("temp.txt", "w")
    0.upto(data.length - 2) do |i|
        max = i # largest value
        (i+1).upto(data.length - 1) { |j| max = j if data[j] > data[max] } 
        data[i], data[max], labels[i], labels[max] = data[max], data[i], labels[max], labels[i] if i != max 

        temp.puts "->", data, "\n", labels, "\n"
    end

    return [data, labels]
end
```

unsorted data:

->
`26.71%
0.17%
0.65%
0.36%
0.17%
2.79%
0.04%
18.03%
0.13%
25.7%
25.18%
0.36%`

Iterations:

->
`26.71%`
**25.7%**
`0.65%
0.36%
0.17%
2.79%
0.04%
18.03%
0.13%`
**0.17%**
`25.18%
0.36%`

->
`26.71%
25.7%`
**25.18%**
`0.36%
0.17%
2.79%
0.04%
18.03%
0.13%
0.17%`
**0.65%**
`0.36%`

**18.03% gets skipped here:**

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%`
**2.79%**
`0.17%
0.36%
0.04%
18.03%
0.13%
0.17%
0.65%`
**0.36%**

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%`
**18.03%**
`0.36%
0.04%`
**0.17%**
`0.13%
0.17%
0.65%
0.36%`

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%`
**0.65%**
`0.04%
0.17%
0.13%
0.17%`
**0.36%**
`0.36%`

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%
0.65%`
**0.36%**
`0.17%
0.13%
0.17%`
**0.04%**
`0.36%`

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%
0.65%
0.36%`
**0.36%**
`0.13%
0.17%
0.04%`
**0.17%**

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%
0.65%
0.36%
0.36%`
**0.17%**
**0.13%**
`0.04%
0.17%`

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%
0.65%
0.36%
0.36%
0.17%`
**0.17%**
`0.04%`
**0.13%**`

->
`26.71%
25.7%
25.18%
2.79%
18.03%
0.65%
0.36%
0.36%
0.17%
0.17%`
**0.13%**`
**0.04%**

I can't figure out why 2.79% gets counted as > 18.03%

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are sorting alphabetically so I would wager the data you are sorting are strings when you wanted them to be floats.